# How to replace number by double of that number in sed?

Tags: replace, sed

How to replace number by double of that number?

For example I have `x7files` and need `x77files`

I have sed `'s/[0-9]/88/'`. It replaces number by `88` so I have `x88files`.

I tried `sed 's/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/'` but it does not work...

Answer (score 1):

try ... `echo x7files | sed -e's/\([0-9]\)/\1\1/g'`

Comment: thank u so much! can u explain what parts mean in this code?? please?

Comment: Hmm I'll try.  In the first part of the regex I use `\(` and `\)` which means save the match into a buffer. In the second part of the regex I have `\1` which mean put the contents of the first buffer here. So `\([0-9]\)` stuffs 7 into the first buffer and I put that buffer twice with `\1\1`.

Comment: Maybe not all systems have `-E`, but slightly clearer to not have to escape the parentheses? `echo x7files | sed -E 's/([0-9])/\1\1/g'`

Comment: In this case the LHS of the substitute command may be replaced by `&` in the RHS. So `sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*/&&/g' file` may be used.